# How to Bind data to Pivot grid in Winforms using c# code in Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, pivot-grid

I wants to bind data to pivot grid using code not by SqlDataSource.

```
private void Report_Summary_Load(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    string cs= configuraitonManager.connectionString["connectionStringDatabase"].connectionString;

    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spStoredProcedureTest",con);
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         con.open();

        SqlDataReader sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        pivotGrid.DataSource = ds;

        PivotGridField Name = new PivotGridField("Name",PivotArea.RowArea);
        PivotGrid.Fields.AddRange(new PivotGridField[] {Name});

        Name.AreaIndex = 0;

        // My pivot grid name is  "pivotGridDemo"

        //How to bind the data to the data area,column area and Row area
     }
}
```

I have 5 Fields

Name,Standard,City,Age,DobYear

I wants to set **Name and City in row area**,**City in column area**,**Age and DobYear in data area**

**Updated**

> The above code is **adding Name is Row field**. But not displaying records

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 pivotGrid.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
 PivotGridField fieldCity  = new PivotGridField("City", PivotArea.ColumnArea);
 fieldCity.Caption = "City";

 PivotGridField fieldName = new PivotGridField("Name", PivotArea.RowArea);
 fieldBureau.Caption = "Name";

 PivotGridField fieldCity = new PivotGridField("City", PivotArea.RowArea);
 fieldBureau.Caption = "City";

 PivotGridField fieldAge  = new PivotGridField("Age", PivotArea.DataArea);   
 fieldQte.CellFormat.FormatType = DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.Numeric;
 fieldAge.AreaIndex = 0;
 PivotGridField fieldDobYear  = new PivotGridField("DobYear ", PivotArea.DataArea);  

  pivotGrid.Fields.AddRange(new PivotGridField[] { fieldCity, fieldName , fieldAge  , fieldDobYear   });
```